# Publishing asp website on Local IIS

Tags: asp.net, mysql

i Have a Asp website that uses MySql database, i want to publish it on my own PC for testing ,
is that possible? and do i need to combine some references with it , or what? and do i need to modify the web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pieces of software required to run you application.

1. You need a web server that's able to serve ASP pages. Either install the full IIS, or if it's only for your own testing you can go with IIS Express (included in e.g. WebMatrix).
2. You need to install a MySql server to run the database. If the MySql drivers are not included in the deploy package of the site, you will need to install those separately as well.

Comment: i have both 1, and 2 ,, what to do next :)

Comment: 1. Copy all the web site files over to the IIS directory. 2. Set up the MySql DB and modify the web.config with the correct connection string. If you're unsure, you should look for a tutorial on how to deploy sites and another one for MySql databases.

Comment: if u used the 'publish website' from visual studio menu., and choose a virtual path , it wont work right?

Comment: publish website from visual studio will setup everything need for the web site. Now you need to setup the database. There's no built in support in Visual Studio for that.

Comment: ok..but how can i do that-the setup of database-?, please forgive my questions but i'm totally newbie :p